# How to make a meta redirect 302?

Tags: html, meta

I am aware of using the meta tag to redirect, like so:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/">
```

...but how do you specifically make it a 302 redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

If you want an HTTP 302 status, then you need to use HTTP and not HTML.